# What's DMZ used for in a home wireless router?

Tags: router, wireless-networking, dmz

As far as I understand, by using DMZ you expose all of the host computer's ports to the Internet. What's that good for?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The DMZ is good if you want to run a home server that can be accessed from outside of your home network (ie web server, ssh, vnc or other remote access protocol).  Typically you would want to run a firewall on the server machine to make sure only the ports that are specifically wanted are allowed access from public computers.

An alternative to using the DMZ is to setup port forwarding.  With port forwarding you can allow only specific ports through your router and you can also specify some ports to go to  different machines if you have multiple servers running behind your router.

Comment: Is it possible to skip the router and connect directly? What if the port is like a phone cable or a coaxial cable?

Answer (score 22):

Please be careful. DMZ in a corporate/professional 
environment (with high-end firewalls) is not the same as for 
a home wireless router (or other NAT routers for home use). 
You may have to use a second NAT router to get the expected 
security (see the article below).

In [episode 3](http://www.grc.com/sn/sn-003.htm) of the [Security Now podcast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Now!) by 
Leo Laporte and security guru Steve Gibson this 
subject was talked about. In the transcript see near "really 
interesting issue because that's the so-called "DMZ," the 
Demilitarized Zone, as it's called on routers.".

From Steve Gibson, http://www.grc.com/nat/nat.htm:

> "As you might imagine, a router's
>   "DMZ" machine, and even a  "port
>   forwarded" machine needs to have
>   substantial security  or it will be
>   crawling with Internet fungus in no
>   time.  That's a BIG problem from a
>   security standpoint. Why? ... a  NAT
>   router has a standard Ethernet switch
>   interconnecting  ALL of its LAN-side
>   ports. There's nothing "separate"
>   about  the port hosting the special
>   "DMZ" machine. It's on the  internal
>   LAN! This means that anything that
>   might crawl into  it through a
>   forwarded router port, or due to its
>   being the  DMZ host, has access to
>   every other machine on the internal 
>   private LAN. (That's really bad.)"

In the article there is also a solution to this problem 
that involves using a second NAT router. There are some 
really good diagrams to illustrate the problem and the 
solution.

Comment: +1. The point of DMZ is to separate a potentially compromised machine from the remainder of the internal network.  Even DD-WRT can't help you here, b/c attacks originating from the DMZ don't pass through the router's ruleset, they just hit the switch.  DMZ is an illusion unless it's on a separate physical connection.

Comment: @hyperslug: actually, with DD-WRT you could configure the DMZ on a completely separate subnet and VLAN.  isolate it entirely from the rest of the network, or configure it so access to the DMZ VLAN from the rest of the internal network *is* firewalled/NAT'd like traffic from the WAN.  that's getting into a complicated configuration, but it is possible with DD-WRT/OpenWRT.

Comment: @quack, the switch isn't port specific, it's a regular switch. So my compromised machine can attack any other machines on the switch w/out being filtered through a router rule.  Regarding the VLAN, I believe I could change the IP (or MAC) on my compromised machine to something on the internal network and hack away.  The 4 ports on the back of some high-end routers behave as 4 NIC's not a 4-port switch, so a rule can be set up like `block all traffic from #4 to #1,#2,#3` which is impossible w/ a L2 switch.

Answer (score 13):

A [DMZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)) or "de-militarized zone" is where you can set up servers or other devices that need to be accessed from outside your network.

What belongs there? Web servers, proxy servers, mail servers etc.

> In a network, the hosts most
>   vulnerable to attack are those that
>   provide services to users outside of
>   the LAN, such as e-mail, web and DNS
>   servers. Because of the increased
>   potential of these hosts being
>   compromised, they are placed into
>   their own subnetwork in order to
>   protect the rest of the network if an
>   intruder was to succeed. Hosts in the
>   DMZ have limited connectivity to
>   specific hosts in the internal
>   network, though communication with
>   other hosts in the DMZ and to the
>   external network is allowed. This
>   allows hosts in the DMZ to provide
>   services to both the internal and
>   external network, while an intervening
>   firewall controls the traffic between
>   the DMZ servers and the internal
>   network clients.

Answer (score 1):

In computer networks, a DMZ (demilitarized zone), also sometimes known as a perimeter network or a screened subnetwork, is a physical or logical subnet that separates an internal local area network (LAN) from other untrusted networks, usually the internet. External-facing servers, resources and services are located in the DMZ. So, they are accessible from the internet, but the rest of the internal LAN remains unreachable. This provides an additional layer of security to the LAN as it restricts the ability of hackers to directly access internal servers and data via the internet.