# Using home computer as a webserver

Tags: networking, webserver, isp

How could I setup a server on my computer? I wish to run a website and think it would be cheaper to run it from my already fast computer and internet.

I have the following questions about the topic:

- Does the ISP block incoming connections to my IP or is it all controlled from the router?
- If I buy a domain and want to use my computer as a server, am I going to be able to tell it the exact IP and Port to connect to? I do not believe port-forwarding port 80 is possible, so I would need to use a separate port if I am able to. Maybe using reverse proxies somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Some ISPs block port 80, some don't. It may be in the terms and conditions for your connection. Consider getting a separate computer for the server, maybe even something like a Raspberry Pi, as web servers are under constant attack. Also, [What's DMZ used for in a home wireless router?](https://superuser.com/q/17572/272824)

Comment: Thanks for the DMZ link, I did not know about that but it seems there is that option in my router

Comment: Have you done any maths to support your belief that it would be cheaper? If it was simpler and cheaper to do this then a lot of companies would have no business model that would allow them to keep operating. Given the amount you don’t know I strongly suggest considering that your assumptions may be less accurate than you might think.

Answer (score 2):

#### I want to run a web server from home

> Does the ISP block incoming connections to my IP or is it all controlled from the router?

That depends on your ISP and also their terms and conditions:

- It might be forbidden to run a web server at all.
- They might allow it but ask you to upgrade your connection because of additional expected traffic or ask you to pay an administrative fee to open the ports.
- They might be using [Carrier Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) which raises another set of technical issues.

> If I buy a domain and want to use my computer as a server, am I going to be able to tell it the exact IP and Port to connect to?

If you have a static IP address then yes. Some ISPs will give you a static IP address for an additional fee.

If you don't have a static IP address then there are services like [Dynamic DNS - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS). Some of these services are free ([Free Dynamic DNS - No-IP.com - Managed DNS Services](https://www.noip.com/free)).

> I do not believe port-forwarding port 80 is possible

Port 80 can usually be forwarded.

> How could I setup a server on my computer?

There are plenty of tutorials. There is also a choice of software that can be used, depending on your technical ability.

Comment: So, tell me if I understand correctly: Carrier Grade NAT means that my IP address within my ISP's reach is different from the one outside of it?

Comment: Basically yes. The ISP uses another layer of NAT between it's network and yours. Multiple customers share the same public IP address within the ISP network which routes the traffic to the correct customer.

Comment: Pretty much. NAT is used (for example) when all the computers on your LAN share a single IP address provided by your ISP. Carrier Grade NAT is similar, but done at the ISP level.

Comment: @Peter  [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm) is worth a read of your ISP is using CGN.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, bros.

Answer (score 1):

Only your ISP can tell you if they are blocking traffic coming in on port 80.  You will need to ensure your account is not behind Carrier Grade NAT, and ideally want a static IP.   (If you don't have these you can bypass ISP blocks and limits using a VPN that delivers you a static IP)

Unless you change from http://www.example.com to http://www.example.com:8081 - if your router wont accept requests on the WAN interface on port 80, you can't change the http port as the port is implied by the protocol, and SRV records ate not used by http/https.   Your router may (or may not) allow you to receive traffic on port 80 and then port forward to another port.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I suppose I will have to have an awkward chat with my ISP where they ask me technical questions that I cannot answer :D